# Do I need to restart my instance for firewall rules to apply

Tags: google-compute-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-console

I have a Windows 2016 server instance running a node.js website on Google Cloud Engine (please don't ask why).
The node.js app does this:

```
var server = http.createServer(app);
server.listen(3000);
```

which, according to the node documentation, listens on every interface.
And indeed, if I connect to the 10.132.x.x address from there, I do see the website.
However, it seems that the port is blocked by the firewall for outside connections.

So I created a new firewall rule which allows tcp:3000 for instances tagged properly. But that doesn't seem to work.

Do I need to restart my instance? Or do anything else?

Comment: Looks like you've already resolved the issue, but FYI you do not need to reboot an instance for a GCE firewall rule change to take effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah, silly me. There is also a firewall on the windows instance itself.